# ListView is not holding activities

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-edittext

i made ListView, i gave to the single row their own activity, but when i use filter (EditText) they are changing position. I mean if first row is called dog and its opening activity with dog image, when i try to find cat row with filter, its always opening dog image cause its on the first place. How can i connected dog row with dog activity? To make them move togerher? Below i paste my code. Please help me :( Intents are filled with String from string.xml (animals was just example)

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<String> elementy = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getSupportActionBar().hide();

    ListaPiosenek();
    powiadomienie();




    }


    private void ListaPiosenek() {

        ArrayList<String> elementy = new ArrayList<String>();
        elementy.add("Dom w górach");
        elementy.add("Jedyne co mam");
        elementy.add("Koncert");
        elementy.add("Ocean");
        elementy.add("Tolerancja");
        elementy.add("Wiesiek idzie");
        elementy.add("Wiosna, ach to ty");
        elementy.add("Chłopaki nie płaczą");
        elementy.add("Dziki Włóczęga");
        elementy.add("Imperatyw");
        elementy.add("Piosenka Turystyczna III");
        elementy.add("Remedium");
        elementy.add("Kiedy będę starą kobietą");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        elementy.add("Król");
        elementy.add("Anna");
        elementy.add("Syn Miasta");
        elementy.add("Samotna fregata");
        elementy.add("Balonik");
        elementy.add("Partyzant");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");;
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        elementy.add("Długość dźwięku samotności");
        //Collections.sort(elementy);




        final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_row,elementy);
        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        list.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        list.requestFocus();



        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        EditText myFilter =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }



        });

    }





    private void powiadomienie() {
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                    int position, long id) {



                if(position==0){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Utwor0.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                        }
                else if(position==1){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(position==2){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor2.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                                }
                else if(position==3){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor3.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
            }
                else if(position==4){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor4.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
        }
                else if (position==5){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor5.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                 else if(position==6){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor6.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==7){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor7.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==8){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor8.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==9){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor9.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==10){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor10.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==11){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor11.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==12){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor12.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==13){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor13.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==14){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor14.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==15){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor15.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==16){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor16.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==17){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor17.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==18){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor18.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }
                else if(position==19){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Utwor19.class);
                    startActivity(i);           
                }




            }
        });











}   


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the elementry ArrayList global to the class and change the logic like this,

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                        int position, long id) {
                String data = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                final int index = elementy.indexOf(data);
                if(index == 0){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Utwor0.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                 }

    }};
```

Answer (score -1):

Its still not working. I read something about viewHolder but its still the same problem. I write VH below, maybe i'm doing something wrong, i dont know.

```
class ViewHolder{
    TextView text=null;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

ViewHolder holder;


if (convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
    convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);
    holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else{
    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}

holder.text.setText(elementy.get(position));
return (convertView);   
}
```